# Will TypeScript support destructuring assignments?

Tags: typescript

Will Typescript support destructuring assignments similar to CoffeeScript?

```
 foo = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}
 {x, z} = foo

 # which will yield
 x == 1 && z == 3
```

Comment: Since TypeScript 1.5 this is now supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it will.**

See this issue in their bug tracker: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/15

`UPDATE:` This is now supported.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it now support from ES6 onwards. You can test the code in your browser(which supports ES6) console itself as below.

```
const user = {name: 'Robkuz', gender: 'Male', looks: 'Great'}
const {name, looks} = user;
```